# OROCOS TypekitRepository::Import errors

Tags: ros, orocos

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am attempting to make a ROS node and OROCOS component communicate with eachother using a ROS topic that has a custom message type.  When I import the OROCOS component that uses the custom message type into the OROCOS Deployer, I get about 15 TypekitRepository::Import errors.  When I quit from the OROCOS Deployer I get a segmentation fault.

I have done some investigating and managed to reduce the number of TypekitRepository::Import errors and eliminate the segmentation fault but I haven’t managed to get rid of all of the errors yet and I don’t understand why I’m getting the errors in the first place.  Any help would be appreciated.

I am using ROS Diamondback 1.4.3 and the latest OROCOS Debian package for Diamandback.

I was following the example at http://www.ros.org/wiki/rtt_ros_integrationThis is what I did:

- Created a ROS package

a.    roscreate-pkg MyRosPkg

b.    roscd MyRosPkg

c.    created  msg/MyMsgType.msg   with the following three lines.

```
string name

int32 val1

float32 val2
```

d.    edited CMakeLists.txt to uncomment the rosbuild_genmsg() line

e.    rosmake MyRosPkg

- Created an OROCOS typekit

a.  rosrun ocl orocreate-pkg MyOrocosTypekit

b.  edited CMakeLists.txt file, added the following just before the orocos_generate_package() line.

```
rosbuild_include(rtt_ros_integration GenerateRTTtypekit)
ros_generate_rtt_typekit(MyRosPkg)
```

c.  Edited the manifest.xml file, added the following just before the </package> line.

```
<depend package="rtt_ros_integration"/>
<depend package="MyRosPkg"/>
    <export>
       <cpp cflags="-I${prefix}/include"/>
    </export>
```

d.  cmake ./ && make

- Created an OROCOS component

a.  rosrun ocl orocreate-pkg MyOrocosComp

b.  Edited the manifest.xml file, added the following just before the </package> line.

```
<depend package=" MyOrocosTypekit"/>
```

c.  Edited the MyOrocosComp-component.hpp file, added the following after the #include  line.

```
#include <MyRosPkg/typekit/MyMsgType.h>
```

d.  cmake ./ && make

- Ran the OROCOS Deployer

a.  rosrun ocl deployer-gnulinux

b.  import(“MyOrocosComp”)

c.  I saw several instances of the following errors (errors included protocol with id of 1, 2, and 42)

```
[ ERROR  ][TypekitRepository::Import] A protocol with id 1 was already added for type /std/string
[ ERROR  ][TypekitRepository::Import] A protocol with id 1 was already added for type /std/vector</double>
```

d.  quit

e.  I saw:

```
TLSF bytes allocated=20480 overhead=6384 max-used=6384 currently-used=6384 still-allocated=0
Segmentation fault
```

- While looking into the problem, I
  found that the
  MyOrocosTypekit-types.hpp and
  MyOrocosComp-types.hpp files that
  were created as part of the template
  contain a structure that has a single
  member --  std::vector<double
  samples.  If I change this to int
  samples in both files, clean, remake,
  and rerun, all of the
  std/vector error messages
  are gone and the Deployer does not
  generate a segmentation fault on
  exit.  I still get the std/string
  error messages.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11744/orocos-typekitrepository::import-errors/) by [Ross P](https://answers.ros.org/users/1297/ross-p/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2011-10-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have found that these problems go away if I don't use rosrun to create MyOrocosTypekit.  So if I replace the •Created a ROS package a - d steps with

a. mkdir MyOrocosTypekit

b. create a MyOrocosTypekit/CMakeLists.txt file that contains

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6.3)
include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)
rosbuild_init()
rosbuild_include(rtt_ros_integration GenerateRTTtypekit)
ros_generate_rtt_typekit(MyRosPkg)
```

c. create a MyOrocosTypekit/manifest.xml file that contains

```
<package>
    <description brief="my typekit">
        This package contains my typekit
    </description>
    <license></license>
    <author>Unknown Author</author>
    <depend package="rtt" />
    <depend package="rtt_ros_integration"/>
    <depend package="MyRosPkg"/>
    <export>
        <cpp cflags="-I${prefix}/include"/>
    </export>
</package>
```

d. cmake ./ && make

Also makeing sure that when I create MyOrocosComponent that I include the modifier to get just component support -- rosrun ocl orocreate-pkg MyOrocosComp **component**

All of the error messages go away.

---

Originally posted by [Ross P](https://answers.ros.org/users/1297/ross-p/) with karma: 16 on 2011-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0